# Issue in getting the correct list items/values using python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list in python like this:

```
list1 = ['Security Name % to Net Assets* DEBENtURES 0.04, Britannia Industries Ltd. EQUity & RELAtED 96.83, HDFC Bank 6.98, ICICI 4.82']
```

if I get the length of this list using `len(list1)` then it gives as 1 simply because it considers all as 1.

How can I transform my list1 such that it would look like this:

```
list1_altered = ['Security Name % to Net Assets* DEBENtURES 0.04', 'Britannia Industries Ltd. EQUity & RELAtED 96.83', 'HDFC Bank 6.98', 'ICICI 4.82']
```

after which upon using `len(list1_altered)` I should be able to get value as 4

I have tried using `replace(",", "\',\'")` however it doesn't give the desired result.

Please help me do this.

Comment: `list1_altered = list1[0].split(', ')`? It seems that `list1` is a list containing exactly one element, which is a string, so to produce the output you want you just need to first get that element `(list1[0])` and then split it on a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the commas by quotes is not going to change the fact that you'll still have a single string. You won't transform an object (string) into another (list of strings) this way.

Use `str.split` to generate a list of multiple strings split on a separator:

```
list1_altered = list1[0].split(',')
```